# JAVA параметризованный тест JUnit

Tags: java, junit, тестирование

есть класс, который считает корни квадратного уравнения, нужно написать параметризованный тест
как правильно передать параметры в тест из метода getArguments?
выдает такую ошибку:

org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [double arg0] in constructor [public com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationNoRootsCasesTesting(double,double,double)].

QuadraticEquation.java

```
public class QuadraticEquation {
    public String solve(double a, double b, double c) {
        if(a == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        double D = b * b - (4 * a * c);
        if(D < 0) {
            return "no roots";
        } else if(D == 0) {
            return Double.toString(b / 2 / a * (-1));
        } else {
            double x1 = (((-1) * b + Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a));
            double x2 = (((-1) * b - Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a));
            return Double.toString(x1) + " " + Double.toString(x2);
        }
    }
}
```

QuadraticEquationNoRootsCasesTesting.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class QuadraticEquationNoRootsCasesTesting {

    protected QuadraticEquation quadraticEquation = new QuadraticEquation();

    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;

    public QuadraticEquationNoRootsCasesTesting(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getArguments")
    public void testNoRootsCase(double a, double b, double c) {
        System.out.println(quadraticEquation.solve(a, b, c));
    }
    static Stream<Arguments> getArguments (){
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                Arguments.of(2.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                Arguments.of(3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                Arguments.of(4.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Простым решением будет убрать параметры из аргументов конструктора `QuadraticEquationNoRootsCasesTesting`, конструктор в вашем случае можно просто удалить, так как он ничего не делает.

Параметры теста передаются через аргуметны тестового метода `public void testNoRootsCase(double a, double b, double c)`.

Comment: все равно остается ошибка 
No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [double arg0] in constructor